# Save only last x MB of audio stream downloaded with curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl, download, wget

I want to download an audio stream (`curl STREAM > out.mp3` ) and analyse it. However, I don't want to store everything, but only the last x MB of this stream, after this everything can be deleted. So the `out.mp3` file's maximal size is x MB and it contains the currently last x MB of the stream.

Can I do this with bash standard tools and so don't analyse the file size myself and using if-else statements?

Comment: Not sure what you consider a "Bash standard tool", but `ffmpeg` could probably do what you want.

Comment: I think this might be a bit to work intensive to run `ffmpeg` continuously the whole time. The solution itself also does not have to depend on mp3-files, `URL` could e.g. be a  continuous system log or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

`tail` displays "the last part of a file". By default it displays the last 10 *lines*, you can use the `-c number` parameter to make it display the last `number` *bytes*. And as a good UNIX citizen, instead of working with files, you can pipe a stream of data to it.

Long story short, you can store the last 1 megabyte of a stream like this:

```
curl -s URL | tail -c 1048576 > last1mb.mp3
```

Comment: For a finite stream this would be good, thank you! But I forgot to mention that the stream is infinite (i.e. a radio stream), so it does never end. Therefore, the `tail` will never be executed (at least for me). I just want to store the last x MB of a radio stream.

Comment: @NiklasWünsche oopsie, kind of an important detail! ;-) I should have seen it coming though :-/ ... I'm afraid this is fraught with many problems. The process would have to rewrite the file periodically. How frequently should that happen? And while the file is being rewritten, what should happen to readers? Should they be interrupted, or should they just finish reading the old content even if it's outdated?

Comment: Can you just cut off a part of an MP3 file and get a valid MP3 file? Aren't there headers and stuff?

Comment: So what I wanted to do is check if a given audio sequence was played inside this stream. So check if the content of `test.mp3` was played already in this stream. However, I don't want to keep all the data but remove it after I checked this condition. I haven't thought about what to do with the readers yet. Maybe one could use 2 files and jump between them if one file was checked completely?